# How to save sessions for particular session in django

Tags: django

I am using request.session to save data.
`sessionid = request.session.session_key`
This id is getting generated and deleted while login and logout.So i want when user would add some items to cart it would be saved in that particular session so if user would not logout then when he comes back would see his added items and if he logs out all added cart item would be deleted.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong?

Comment: Just save the shopping cart indexed by the `sessionid` and repopulate it when the user makes a request.

Comment: @henrikstroem like `sessionid[0] = 'item1' , sessionid[1] = 'item2'` ?

Comment: I would rather make a model for that purpose, you need the information outside the request/response cycle.